# Why the material time derivative of a material field $F$ equals to the directional derivative of $F$ in the direction of the velocity vector $v$?

Tags: kinematics, solid-mechanics

I am reading the book *Nonlinear Solid Mechanics A Continuum Approach for Engineering by Gerhard A. Holzapfel, Chapter 2.3* and find one equation confusing, which is displayed in the pitcure.
[image]

Here in the pitcure, $F$ is a smooth material field, denoted with $F(X,t)$.
The equation (1.266) is as follows,
[image]

I am wondering why eq(2.20) makes sense. Can someone helpe me?

---

My current progress:
From the book, the definition of left-hand side of the equation is
\begin{equation}
\dot{\mathcal{F}}(\mathbf{X}, t)=\frac{\mathrm{D} \mathcal{F}(\mathbf{X}, t)}{\mathrm{D} t}=\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{F}(\mathbf{X}, t)}{\partial t}\right)_{\mathbf{x}}
\end{equation}
The subscript $X$ means that $X$ is hold constant when taking the partial derivative.
The right-hand side that I calculated is
\begin{equation}
D_{\textbf{v}}\mathcal{F}(\textbf{X},t)= \frac{d}{d\epsilon}\mathcal{F}(\textbf{X}+\epsilon\textbf{v},t) | _{\epsilon=0}=
\frac{\partial \mathcal{F}}{\partial \textbf{X}_1}\cdot\frac{v_1}{|\textbf{v}|}+
\frac{\partial \mathcal{F}}{\partial \textbf{X}_2}\cdot\frac{v_2}{|\textbf{v}|}+
\frac{\partial \mathcal{F}}{\partial \textbf{X}_3}\cdot\frac{v_3}{|\textbf{v}|}
\end{equation}

I don't know how these two equation can be made equal. Could some help me on it?

Comment: Eq. 1.266 is mentioned in the text. It might be useful to report it in your question

Comment: Added, thx for reminding me!